# MEF & separate Interface assembly leads to "Interface for every class"

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, interface, mef

I'm getting my feet wet with DI/IoC and MEF in particular.

I have a web application that has two types of parts (maybe more someday) defined by interfaces which need access to the whole environment. The application has a list with concrete implementations for each type, composed by MEF.

The environment consists of:

- several repositories
- current application request
- render engine
- navigation engine
- plus some static utility classes

How can I put the Interface definitions in a seperate assembly and at the same time specify the environment injection?

Obviously, I can't just reference the main assembly because that needs to reference the contract assembly and I can't create a circular reference.

It seems that I need to create an interface for each of the environment classes, and their publicly available types and so on... There has to be a better way?!

Maybe I'm also missing the obvious bigger flaw here, if anyone could point it out for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to decouple your abstractions from their implementations (always a worthy goal), you should define those abstractions in their own assembly.

From the implementation side, this is easy to deal with, becuase you need to reference the abstractions to implement them. There's no way around that whether you use MEF or not, so that's as it has always been:

```
[Import(typeof(IFoo))]
public class MyFoo : IFoo { }
```

However, as you say, this means that you can't reference your **Composition Root** from the abstraction library. However, that is as it should be, because the abstractions shouldn't worry about how they get composed.

In other words, you must implement the composition of the dependencies outside of the abstraction library. A good candidate for that is the executable itself, whereas you would keep all your concrete implementations in one or separate libraries.

The abstraction library will have no references, while both consumers and implementers would need to reference it, so a dependency graph might look like this:

```
Composition Root --> Abstractions <-- Implementations
```

Where the arrows denote a reference.

Comment: "can't reference your Composition Root from the abstraction library" - That's the goal, but also the source of my confusion. If my abstractions have a property of type "Engine", which is defined and implemented in my implementation library, do I need to create an interface "IEngine" for this type in the abstraction library too? Now, if I have multiple types in need to reference, each again with their own dependencies, I'd need to abstract all of those into the abstraction library, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. All those extra interfaces may seem like a lot over overhead, but each is actually a **Seam** where you decouple implementer from consumer. The end result is a looser coupled system. The benefit may not be immediately obvious, but once you begin to experience the power of consuming and exposing abstractions instead of concrete types, you will never want to go back :)

Comment: thanks, so what I thought was too much, is actually perfectly fine and needed!

Comment: amen - once I discovered the secrets of abstractions and interfaces, I use them all over the place.

Comment: I have yet to find a sample of what a composition root looks like. I see many posts stating "in your composition root", etc but never any examples or instruction to those who are learning DI and never seen a CR before.