# Separate controllers for child entities

Tags: oop, model-view-controller

This is probably very basic question but I can't find straight answer to it, 
I was thinking about it for a while and still didn't figure out what is best practice?

In parent - child relationship, e.g. Department / Employee should I have actions like:

```
DepartmentController -> addEmpoyee(deptId) 
DepartmentController -> editEmpoyee(empId)
DepartmentController -> employees(deptId)
```

Or rather create separate controller for Employee operations? 
    EmployeeController -> add(deptId)
    EmployeeController -> edit(empId)
    EmployeeController -> list(deptId)

Second approach makes sense to me but the first seems to be logical as well as employees are child entities of dept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a `DepartmentCrudController` gathering those methods (index, show, create, delete, new, edit).

Indeed, CRUD is **ONE** responsibility in itself, so does not break Single Responsibility Principle.

However, associated commands called by controller (take a look at CQRS for instance), if contain some business logic (task-driven UI), should themselves be separated in order to be less sensitive to change, increasing the flexibility of your application.

But for a simple CRUD, one service layer class is enough.

Your controller should be a simple **humble object** delegating to your use cases (services layer), meaning without ANY business logic at all.

Comment: thanks so I guess I will use separate controller - if I understand this correctly. This makes sense to me although sometimes it looks easier to just throw all the related logic to parent controller...

Comment: @GrumpyHat No I meant the reverse:  Keep just one controller. CRUD represents one responsibility by itself, especially in the controller since it aims to be a simple humble object.

Comment: Right, but in that case the controller may grow quite big, as I will have add,edit,delete,search(index),view for dept and again for employee as they are using different forms (this is a web app). On top of that I will most likely have more custom methods for both parent and child entities...

Comment: Custom methods should be part of another controller. I worked today on a similar CRUD controller, and it takes about 3 lines maximum by methods. (since humble object => only delegation to model). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324049/what-is-the-humble-object-pattern-and-when-is-it-useful

Comment: I think I kinda have it this way actually. I have a generic controller which handles common tasks view, add etc. All other controllers inherit from the generic one. All non standard logic is in separate controllers. so I probably should have separate controllers for dept and employee BUT only have custom logic in there? Or am I still missing the point?

Comment: You want to have `DepartmentCrudController` (CRUD for departement), `EmployeeCrudController` (CRUD for employee), and common methods on the parent one, let's call it, `BaseCrudController`. This BaseCrudController might be itself inherits from `BaseController` that is the root of all. All methods that aren't common to both `DepartmentCrudController` and `EmployeeCrudController` AND having nothing to do with CRUD, should be part of a complete other controller or better just another model.