# Inject Dependencies into Validation Attribute using ASP.NET Core's WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building a Custom Validation Attribute in ASP.NET Core WebAPI. I need to access IDataProtector in my validator and another service I'm using to access the database. I've searched and wasn't ab;e to find any documentation for this. ActionFilters have the option of using ServiceFilter but there doesn't seem to be any option for Validation Attribute. Any ideas?

Comment: You should not inject dependencies into attributes as expressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29916075/264697), [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/) and [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because validation attributes are typically defined on properties, they can't receive a reference via the constructor.  At best if you did really deep into model binding, there may be something to customize to allow property injection, but most practically I just get a reference to the dependency resolver in the Validate method, and call the appropriate method.

Answer (score 33):

Use the GetService() method of the ValidationContext to get your database.
i.e.

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
  MyDbContext db = (MyDbContext) validationContext.GetService(typeof(MyDbContext));
  //...
}
```

Comment: And because the `ValidationContext` implements `IServiceProvider`, adding `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` will add the rest of the useful extensions to allow `validationContext.GetService<MyDbContext>()` without explicit casting.

Comment: Where does GetSerivce fetch the dependency from ?

Answer (score 5):

You can override IsValid method and use validationContext to resolve dependency:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)  
{
    var service = (IExternalService) validationContext.GetService(typeof(IExternalService));
    // use service
}
```

Comment: that's somehow, isn't cool, it returns 400 HTTP error, instead of going through controller, ModelState.IsValid(), I need to access the bool returning one, that microsoft used to override in required and etc...

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar requirement where additional data was needed to be passed to an attribute to provide enough context for it to perform the validation.

We came up with a way to build up a context object which could be passed to attributes. I blogged about it [here](https://rossjayjones.github.io/dotnetcore/aspnetcore/mvc/dotnet/2018/09/09/injecting-services-into-validation-attributes-aspnetcore.html).

We are using the async api to perform data access which presented some additional challenges.