# Injecting a logger with constructor dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'm trying to refactor some code to use .NET Core dependency injection via mapping services in startup.cs. I would like to inject an IRequestDatabaseLogger here instead of newing it up. However it requires the context in the constructor. How can I achieve this? Is it even possible without an DI framework or even then?

```
    public class ActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var requestDatabaseLogger = new RequestDatabaseLogger(context);
            long logId = requestDatabaseLogger.Log();

            context.HttpContext.AddCurrentLogId(logId);

            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Prevent doing anything useful in attributes. Attributes should be passive, as explained [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/) and [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29916075/264697

Comment: I think you mean *Avoid* not Prevent (doing anything useful)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However it requires the context in the constructor.

Letting the construction of application components depend on runtime data is an anti-pattern, as described [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). That article describes how to solve these problems in general.

In your case this probably means that your component should depend on ASP.NET Core's `IHttpContextAccessor` abstraction instead, which is a pattern described in the referenced article.

Alternatively, as described in the article, you can pass through the required runtime data to the logger using it's `Log` method.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the TypeFilter to achieve this, and wrap the filter that has the dependency (in this case on a logger or a context) inside of the filter. I show a detailed example of this in my [MSDN Article on ASP.NET Core Filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt767699.aspx). The related source code is [here](https://github.com/ardalis/GettingStartedWithFilters) (look at the ValidateAuthorExists filter).

Here's what it might look like in your scenario:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public MyFilterAttribute():base(typeof(MyFilterImpl))
    {
    }

    private class MyFilterImpl : IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        public MyFilterImpl( *inject dependencies here*)
        {}
    }
}
```

This is how you can use attributes in .NET Core while still injecting dependencies into the underlying action filter. I also cover this in my upcoming ASP.NET Core Quickstart course on DevIQ.com (look for it end of this month).

Answer (score 0):

Inject a `RequestDatabaseLoggerFactory` in the constructor, which can be used to create a `RequestDatabaseLogger` instance.

```
public interface IRequestDatabaseLoggerFactory {
    IRequestDatabaseLogger Create(ActionExecutingContext context);
}
public class RequestDatabaseLoggerFactory : IRequestDatabaseLoggerFactory {
    public IRequestDatabaseLogger Create(ActionExecutingContext context) {
        return new RequestDatabaseLogger(context);
    }
}

public class ActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ActionFilter(IRequestDatabaseLoggerFactory factory) {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    private readonly IRequestDatabaseLoggerFactory _factory;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var requestDatabaseLogger = _factory.Create(context);
        long logId = requestDatabaseLogger.Log();

        context.HttpContext.AddCurrentLogId(logId);

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
```

}

Comment: I advise against the use of factory abstractions as shown here, as explained [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100).