# Validating a token using ActionFilterAttribute and a Repository using NET Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building a Web API using NET Core + Autofac.

This is my BaseRepository which gets appsettings.json values via injection:

```
public class BaseRepository
{
    protected string ConnectionString { get; }

    public BaseRepository(IOptions<CustomSettings> customConfig)
    {
        ConnectionString = customConfig.Value.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

This is how I configure IOptions:

```
services.Configure<CustomSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("CustomSettings"));
```

I need to validate the content of a header through an Stored Procedure which is invoked within a Repository. I want to do it by using an ActionFilter instead of in every controller's method.

```
public class ValidateRequestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        var isValidToken =
            new TokenRepository(_customSettings, _cache).ValidToken(token); // this is an error as both parameters do not exist at this moment

        if (!isValidToken)
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
    }
}
```

My plan is to invoke the filter in every controller like this:

```
[ValidateRequest]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
```

I haven't found a way to inject _customSettings (IOptions) nor _cache (IMemoryCache) to my custom ActionFilter. After reading, I'm starting to think it won't be possible.

Another option would be to access appsettings.json from my BaseRepository?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29916075/264697

Comment: About `IOption<T>`, prevent letting application components take a dependency on it, as explained [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html#working-with-ioption-t).

Comment: before using IOption<T> I had made it work with IConfigurationRoot, but I guess it is the same as I was injecting it to my BaseRepository anyway, isn't it? my biggest concern is how to get the connection string in my repositories from appsettings.json without injecting anything, or is this a bad practice? @Steven

Comment: No, injecting a connection string directly is not bad practice at all. But you can also inject `CustomSettings` directly. The moral here is: you don't need `IOption<T>`.

Comment: I was able to handle this without an issue using NET 4.5, by using a custom IAuthorizationFilter and grabbing the connectiong string from my BaseRepository through ConfigurationManager. I'm stuck on how to get this done using NET Core, could you please advise? I think I'm only missing how to read appsettings.json from my BaseRepository.

Comment: ...since I'm noticing I can't or mustn't inject objets to a custom ActionFilterAttribute which needs to invoke a Repository. Btw, thanks for the articles you've provided me so far.

Comment: decided to implement Identity based on claims to get this done, working on it