# Switch threads only in ViewModel

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

Android Studio 4

RxJava2, MVVM.

**Approach#1**

In my activity:

```
 val dispose = filmsRxJavaViewModel.filmsListSingle
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe( {// call before .doOnTerminate()
                Debug.d(TAG, "initLogic: doOnSubscribe:")
                binding.progressBarLayout.containerProgressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
            })
            .doOnTerminate({// call before .subscribe()
                Debug.d(TAG, "initLogic: doOnTerminate:")
                binding.filmsSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                binding.progressBarLayout.containerProgressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)
            })
            // Only after call subscribe() then execute network request
            .subscribe({ filmsList -> // success
                Debug.d(TAG, "initLogic: subscribe: success")
                // Hide swipe to refresh icon animation
                if (filmsList.size > 0) { // list<Film>
filmItemListDataBindingAdapter!!.updateData(filmsList)
                } else {
                    binding.filmsRecyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.emptyLayoutContainer.root.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }, {// error
                    throwable ->
                Debug.e(TAG, "initLogic: subscribe: error = $throwable")
                Toast.makeText(this, throwable.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            })
```

in my ViewModel:

```
class FilmsRxJavaViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    companion object {
        private val TAG = FilmsRxJavaViewModel::class.java.name
    }

    lateinit var filmsListSingle: Single<List<Film>>

    init {
        Debug.d(TAG, "init:")
        loadData()
    }

    fun loadData() {
        Debug.d(TAG, "loadData:")
        filmsListSingle = TransportServiceRxJava.getFilms()
    }

}
```

And my Transport and Retrofit interface

```
fun getFilms() : Single<List<Film>> {
            return testRxJavaRestClient.getFilms()
        }

import io.reactivex.Single
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface TestRxJavaRestClient {

    @GET("films")
    fun getFilms(): Single<List<Film>>

}
```

And as result it's work. Nice... but the problem with this approach that  Activity know about switch between threads.

So I use another approach.

**Approach#2**

```
val dispose = filmsRxJavaViewModel.filmsListSingle
            .doOnSubscribe( {// call before .doOnTerminate()
                Debug.d(TAG, "initLogic: doOnSubscribe:")
                binding.progressBarLayout.containerProgressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
            })
            .doOnTerminate({// call before .subscribe()
                Debug.d(TAG, "initLogic: doOnTerminate:")
                binding.filmsSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                binding.progressBarLayout.containerProgressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)
            })
            // Only after call subscribe() then execute network request
            .subscribe({ filmsList -> // success
                Debug.d(TAG, "initLogic: subscribe: success")
                // Hide swipe to refresh icon animation
                if (filmsList.size > 0) { // list<Film>
filmItemListDataBindingAdapter!!.updateData(filmsList)
                } else {
                    binding.filmsRecyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.emptyLayoutContainer.root.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }, {// error
                    throwable ->
                Debug.e(TAG, "initLogic: subscribe: error = $throwable")
                Toast.makeText(this, throwable.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            })
```

In my ViewModel:

```
fun loadData() {
        Debug.d(TAG, "loadData:")
        filmsListSingle = TransportServiceRxJava.getFilms()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }
```

As you can see switch between threads I move to viewModel.

I think this is a correct way. Only viewModel must need about switch between threads. As result my Activity work only with view widgets (e.g. show toast).

Is this a correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Putting the heavy Rx logic inside the ViewModel is the way to go.

This is for testability: the Fragments and Activities are heavyweight and difficult to test. By contrast, the ViewModel is amenable to testing.

So we make the Fragment and Activities "stupid" following the [humble object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324049/what-is-the-humble-object-pattern-and-when-is-it-useful) pattern.

The Fragment and Activities should merely observe changes to a ViewModel's model that is a bag of primitives. This is done by the ViewModel exposing LiveData. For transient changes to the View, like a Toast, the Fragment or Activity can observe LiveData of a stream of events that expire when handled.

Please see the Android Architecture Blueprints and `SingleLiveEvent` [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples)

Also, they are not "threads" in RxJava - they're schedulers.