# User scoped dependencies in a custom ASP.NET Core Action Filter?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, actionfilterattribute, custom-action-filter

According to the official documentation here:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#authorization-filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authorization-filters)

To implement a custom `ActionFilter` in ASP.NET Core I have three choices:

- SeviceFilterAttribute
- TypeFilterAttribute
- IFilterFactory

But for all three it is stated that:

> Shouldn't be used with a filter that depends on services with a lifetime other than singleton.

So how can I inject scoped services in my custom `ActionFilter`? I can easily get a scoped service from the current `HttpContext` like this:

```cs
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
{
    ISubscriptionHelper subscriptionHelper =
        actionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
            .GetRequiredService<ISubscriptionHelper>();
}
```

But then I am wondering if I am doing something wrong? What is the correct way to depend on scoped services in a custom ActionFilterAttribute?

Answer (score 7):

Resolving services from the `HttpContext.RequestServices` will correctly resolve scoped and transient instances without causing any problems such as [Captive Dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). In case resolved components implement `IDisposable`, they will be disposed of when the request ends. ASP.NET Core passes on the current `HttpContext` object to filter's `OnActionExecuting` method and that `HttpContext` gives access to the DI Container.

This is completely different from injecting those services into the constructor, because the action filter will be cached for the lifetime of the application. Any dependencies stored in private fields will, therefore, live as long as that filter. This leads to the so called *Captive Dependency* problem.

Code that accesses the DI Container (the `HttpContext.RequestServices` is your gateway into the DI Container) should be centralized in the infrastructure code of the startup path of the application—the so called [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). Accessing your DI Container outside the Composition Root inevitably leads to the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/)—this should not be taken lightly.

To prevent this, it is advised to keep the amount of code inside the action filter as small as possible and implement the filter as a [Humble Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324049/what-is-the-humble-object-pattern-and-when-is-it-useful). This means that preferably, the only line of code inside the filter is the following:

```cs
actionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
    .GetRequiredService<ISomeService>() // resolve service
    .DoSomeOperation(); // delegate work to service
```

This means all (application) logic is moved to the `ISomeService` implementation, allowing the action filter to become a Humble Object.

Comment: I don't understand how resolving the ISomeService in the filter is not service locator anti-pattern? It just resolves a wrapper service instead of just resolving the required services directly. Or maybe I don't understand the point of the Humble Object in this case

Comment: Whether or not resolving a service from a container-like abstraction is the Service Locator anti-pattern depends on the location where it is used. Only when used *outside* the Composition Root do we speak about the Service Locator anti-pattern. For more information about this topic, I'll refer to my previous work [here](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) and [here](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/). But long storty short: the Humble Object is (or should be) part of our Composition Root.