# How to tell Ninject to bind to an implementation it doesn't have a reference to

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject, separation-of-concerns

I'm using [NinjectMVC3](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Ninject.MVC3) in my ASP.NET MVC3 project.

I have 3 layers

- Foo.Web
- Foo.Services
- Foo.Data

Foo.Web references Foo.Services but not Foo.Data. One of my services looks like this

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    private readonly IFooRepository _fooRepository;

    public FooService(IFooRepository fooRepository)
    {
        _fooRepository = fooRepository;
    }

    // ...
}
```

NinjectMVC3 executes this bootstrapping method in the Foo.Web startup

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IFooService>().To<FooService>();
    kernel.Bind<IFooRepository>().To<FooRepository>();
    // Foo.Web doesn't know what FooRepository is
}
```

How can I inject FooServices dependencies from Foo.Web?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267525/dal-bll-gui-composition-root-how-to-setup-di-bindings

Answer (score 7):

To get you pointed in the right direction, I'd suggest you take a look at the [onion architecture.](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/)

It's basic premise is that any code can depend on layers more central. In your scenario (and it's a common one for MVC3 apps using the Repository pattern) your UI should have a reference to the services layer and it's acceptable to have a reference to the data layer.

If you're willing to accept that (it's a hard pill to swallow if you're coming from a classic N-tier setup, I know), then your situation becomes much simpler.

With Ninject you now do something as follows:

In your NinjectMVC3.cs file your CreateKernel becomes

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var modules = new INinjectModule[]
                          {
                              new ServiceDIModule(),
                              new RepositoryDIModule()
                          };

        var kernel = new StandardKernel(modules);

        //RegisterServices(kernel); <-- Only if you have some custom binding 
        //                              that are UI specific
        return kernel;
    }
```

Now, in your services layer, you add a reference to Ninject (just plain Ninject via NuGet, not the MVC3 dropin via NuGet) and add what I called above the ServiceDIModule which looks like this:

```
using Ninject.Modules;

namespace MyServiceLayer
{
    public class ServiceDIModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            //Bind Services
            Bind<IPracticeService>().To<PracticeService>().InRequestScope();
        }
    }
}
```

and you repeat the same process for the Data Tier injections you may have (UnitofWork, DatabaseFactory, IFooRepository, etc.)

```
namespace MyDataLayer
{
    public class RepositoryDIModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            //Bind Repos
            Bind<IFooRepository>().To<FooRepository>().InRequestScope();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you have access to all of the bindings you need way upfront. So, your question to me really boils down to a shift in thinking. If you can accept (begrudgingly or otherwise) the onion concept, your scenario resolves itself cleanly.

You can also check out [Project Silk](http://silk.codeplex.com/) and [CodeCampServer](http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/). They both implement the "onion" concept to some degree (Silk for sure, I'm looking at the solution right now and the UI web project contains a ref to the Data proj which contains all the Repos)

Let me know what you think.

Comment: interesting. i'm still not sure if you're just trying to get me fired ;) but I'll play around with the idea. thanks.